# how to class wrap a list in c# for xml serializing

Tags: c#, xml

How can one class wrap a list in c# for xml serializing?
I would like to add a root. maybe a class wrapper is not a good idea. And should I use a different aprouch?

When I serialize the following class:

```
public class Parts
{
    //main class   
    [XmlElement("Access")]
    public List<Access> AccessDB = new List<Access>
    {
        new Access
        {
            Items = new[] {
             new Component { Name = "dbName" }
            ,new Component { Name = "DbElement" } }
            , Scope = "GlobalVariable", UId = "21"
        },

        new Access
        {
            Items = new[] {
             new Component { Name = "TagName" } }
            , Scope = "GlobalVariable", UId = "22"
        }
    };

}
```

I get:

```
<Parts>
  <Access Scope="Scope" UId="21">
    <Symbol>
      <Component Name="Name" />
      <Component Name="Name" />
    </Symbol>
  </Access>
  <Access Scope="Scope" UId="22">
    <Symbol>
      <Component Name="Name" />
    </Symbol>
  </Access>
  <Part Name="PartName" UId="23" />
</Parts>
```

but what I need is:

```
<myroot>
    <Parts>
      <Access Scope="Scope" UId="21">
        <Symbol>
          <Component Name="Name" />
          <Component Name="Name" />
        </Symbol>
      </Access>
      <Access Scope="Scope" UId="22">
        <Symbol>
          <Component Name="Name" />
        </Symbol>
      </Access>
      <Part Name="PartName" UId="23" />
    </Parts>
</myroot>
```

any advice is very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `myroot` element is only required to be present in the `xml` output, you can add it during the serialization.
Use an `XmlWriter` as output target for the serialization.
Before serializing the `Parts` instance, you use the `XmlWriter` to create the `myroot` element.

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true  };
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder, settings))
{
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("myroot"); // Writes <myroot>

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parts));
    var parts = new Parts();
    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, parts);

    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // Writes </myroot>
}
```

Comment: Hi pfx, thanks for your answer. your suggestion works. For now I have used the stringbuilder and added the `xdocoment.parse()` function to prevent writing the xml-code in one line.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is also possible to class wrap the other classes, but the instance of the class must be public. In code:

```
public class myRoot
    {
        public Parts Parts = new Parts();
    }
```

and then serialize the class `myRoot`